# CSS3: floating divs over a non-floated div

Tags: css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PA5T5/1/

I have 3 divs, 2 are floating and 1 isn't. The 2 floating divs are superimposed over the non-floating div. This is the effect I want to achieve. My question is this: is this how it is supposed to work? It seems like it shouldn't work. Is this a proper way to superimpose divs without having to use absolute positioning?

```
#box1 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
#box2 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
#box3 {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply set `#box3` css to `overflow: hidden` and then make box1 and box2 children inside of box3?  http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/PA5T5/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position fixed;

or apply margin-top to elements floating.

```
#box1 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:cyan;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
#box2 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:pink;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
#box3 {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    margin-top: -25px
}
```

see : http://jsfiddle.net/PA5T5/4/